# Changing height of a sidemenu

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9, sidebar

[This is my actual view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZtLV.png)

I want that the sidemenu begins at the first grey line and not on the top of the view. I would be glad if I could get an answer how i can set the height of it but i am also happy if someone could suggest me a workaround like hiding it behind the searchbar and segmented control. Thank you in advance.

This is my ENSideMenu.swift implementation

```
import UIKit

@objc public protocol ENSideMenuDelegate {
optional func sideMenuWillOpen()
optional func sideMenuWillClose()
optional func sideMenuDidOpen()
optional func sideMenuDidClose()
optional func sideMenuShouldOpenSideMenu () -> Bool
}

@objc public protocol ENSideMenuProtocol {
var sideMenu : ENSideMenu? { get }
func setContentViewController(contentViewController: UIViewController)
}

public enum ENSideMenuAnimation : Int {
case None
case Default
}
/**
The position of the side view on the screen.

 - Left:  Left side of the screen
 - Right: Right side of the screen
 */
public enum ENSideMenuPosition : Int {
case Left
case Right
}

public extension UIViewController {
/**
 Changes current state of side menu view.
 */
public func toggleSideMenuView () {
    sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.toggleMenu()
}
/**
 Hides the side menu view.
 */
public func hideSideMenuView () {
    sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.hideSideMenu()
}
/**
 Shows the side menu view.
 */
public func showSideMenuView () {
    sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.showSideMenu()
}

/**
 Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the side menu is showed.

 :returns: BOOL value
 */
public func isSideMenuOpen () -> Bool {
    let sieMenuOpen = self.sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.isMenuOpen
    return sieMenuOpen!
}

/**
 * You must call this method from viewDidLayoutSubviews in your content       view controlers so it fixes size and position of the side menu when the screen
 * rotates.
 * A convenient way to do it might be creating a subclass of UIViewController that does precisely that and then subclassing your view controllers from it.
 */
func fixSideMenuSize() {
    if let navController = self.navigationController as? ENSideMenuNavigationController {
        navController.sideMenu?.updateFrame()
    }
}
/**
 Returns a view controller containing a side menu

 :returns: A `UIViewController`responding to `ENSideMenuProtocol` protocol
 */
public func sideMenuController () -> ENSideMenuProtocol? {
    var iteration : UIViewController? = self.parentViewController
    if (iteration == nil) {
        return topMostController()
    }
    repeat {
        if (iteration is ENSideMenuProtocol) {
            return iteration as? ENSideMenuProtocol
        } else if (iteration?.parentViewController != nil && iteration?.parentViewController != iteration) {
            iteration = iteration!.parentViewController
        } else {
            iteration = nil
        }
    } while (iteration != nil)

    return iteration as? ENSideMenuProtocol
}

internal func topMostController () -> ENSideMenuProtocol? {
    var topController : UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    if (topController is UITabBarController) {
        topController = (topController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController
    }
    while (topController?.presentedViewController is ENSideMenuProtocol) {
        topController = topController?.presentedViewController
    }

    return topController as? ENSideMenuProtocol
}
}

public class ENSideMenu : NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
/// The width of the side menu view. The default value is 160.
public var menuWidth : CGFloat = 90.0 {
    didSet {
        needUpdateApperance = true
        updateFrame()
    }

    }
private var menuPosition:ENSideMenuPosition = .Right
private var blurStyle: UIBlurEffectStyle = .Light
///  A Boolean value indicating whether the bouncing effect is enabled. The default value is TRUE.
public var bouncingEnabled :Bool = true
/// The duration of the slide animation. Used only when `bouncingEnabled` is FALSE.
public var animationDuration = 0.25
private let sideMenuContainerView =  UIView()
private(set) var menuViewController : UIViewController!
private var animator : UIDynamicAnimator!
private var sourceView : UIView!
private var needUpdateApperance : Bool = false
/// The delegate of the side menu
public weak var delegate : ENSideMenuDelegate?
private(set) var isMenuOpen : Bool = false
/// A Boolean value indicating whether the left swipe is enabled.
public var allowLeftSwipe : Bool = true
/// A Boolean value indicating whether the right swipe is enabled.
public var allowRightSwipe : Bool = true
public var allowPanGesture : Bool = true
private var panRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer?

/**
 Initializes an instance of a `ENSideMenu` object.

 :param: sourceView   The parent view of the side menu view.
 :param: menuPosition The position of the side menu view.

 :returns: An initialized `ENSideMenu` object, added to the specified view.
 */
public init(sourceView: UIView, menuPosition: ENSideMenuPosition, blurStyle: UIBlurEffectStyle = .Light) {
    super.init()
    self.sourceView = sourceView
    self.menuPosition = menuPosition
    self.blurStyle = blurStyle
    self.setupMenuView()


    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView:sourceView)
    animator.delegate = self

    self.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
    panRecognizer!.delegate = self
    sourceView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer!)

    // Add right swipe gesture recognizer
    let rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleGesture:")
    rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction =  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right

    // Add left swipe gesture recognizer
    let leftSwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleGesture:")
    leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left

    if (menuPosition == .Left) {
        sourceView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGestureRecognizer)
        sideMenuContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeGestureRecognizer)
    }
    else {
        sideMenuContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGestureRecognizer)
        sourceView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeGestureRecognizer)
    }

}
/**
 Initializes an instance of a `ENSideMenu` object.

 :param: sourceView         The parent view of the side menu view.
 :param: menuViewController A menu view controller object which will be placed in the side menu view.
 :param: menuPosition       The position of the side menu view.

 :returns: An initialized `ENSideMenu` object, added to the specified view, containing the specified menu view controller.
 */
public convenience init(sourceView: UIView, menuViewController: UIViewController, menuPosition: ENSideMenuPosition, blurStyle: UIBlurEffectStyle = .Light) {
    self.init(sourceView: sourceView, menuPosition: menuPosition, blurStyle: blurStyle)
    self.menuViewController = menuViewController
    self.menuViewController.view.frame = sideMenuContainerView.bounds
    self.menuViewController.view.autoresizingMask =  [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
    sideMenuContainerView.addSubview(self.menuViewController.view)
}
/*
public convenience init(sourceView: UIView, view: UIView, menuPosition: ENSideMenuPosition) {
self.init(sourceView: sourceView, menuPosition: menuPosition)
view.frame = sideMenuContainerView.bounds
view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
sideMenuContainerView.addSubview(view)
}
*/
/**
Updates the frame of the side menu view.
*/
func updateFrame() {
    var width:CGFloat
    var height:CGFloat
    (width, height) = adjustFrameDimensions( sourceView.frame.size.width, height: sourceView.frame.size.height)
    let menuFrame = CGRectMake(
        (menuPosition == .Left) ?
            isMenuOpen ? 0 : -menuWidth-1.0 :
            isMenuOpen ? width - menuWidth : width+1.0,
        sourceView.frame.origin.y,
        menuWidth,
        height
    )
    sideMenuContainerView.frame = menuFrame
}

private func adjustFrameDimensions( width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat ) -> (CGFloat,CGFloat) {
    if floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 &&
        (UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight ||
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft) {
                // iOS 7.1 or lower and landscape mode -> interchange width and height
                return (height, width)
    }
    else {
        return (width, height)
    }

}

private func setupMenuView() {

    // Configure side menu container
    updateFrame()

    sideMenuContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    sideMenuContainerView.clipsToBounds = false
    sideMenuContainerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    sideMenuContainerView.layer.shadowOffset = (menuPosition == .Left) ? CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0) : CGSizeMake(-1.0, -1.0)
    sideMenuContainerView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.25
    sideMenuContainerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.125
    sideMenuContainerView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: sideMenuContainerView.bounds).CGPath

    sourceView.addSubview(sideMenuContainerView)

    if (NSClassFromString("UIVisualEffectView") != nil) {
        // Add blur view
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: blurStyle)) as UIVisualEffectView
        visualEffectView.frame = sideMenuContainerView.bounds
        visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
        sideMenuContainerView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    }
    else {
        // TODO: add blur for ios 7
    }
}

private func toggleMenu (shouldOpen: Bool) {
    if (shouldOpen && delegate?.sideMenuShouldOpenSideMenu?() == false) {
        return
    }
    updateSideMenuApperanceIfNeeded()
    isMenuOpen = shouldOpen
    var width:CGFloat
    var height:CGFloat
    (width, height) = adjustFrameDimensions( sourceView.frame.size.width, height: sourceView.frame.size.height)
    if (bouncingEnabled) {

        animator.removeAllBehaviors()

        var gravityDirectionX: CGFloat
        var pushMagnitude: CGFloat
        var boundaryPointX: CGFloat
        var boundaryPointY: CGFloat

        if (menuPosition == .Left) {
            // Left side menu
            gravityDirectionX = (shouldOpen) ? 1 : -1
            pushMagnitude = (shouldOpen) ? 20 : -20
            boundaryPointX = (shouldOpen) ? menuWidth : -menuWidth-2
            boundaryPointY = 20
        }
        else {
            // Right side menu
            gravityDirectionX = (shouldOpen) ? -1 : 1
            pushMagnitude = (shouldOpen) ? -20 : 20
            boundaryPointX = (shouldOpen) ? width-menuWidth : width+menuWidth+2
            boundaryPointY =  -20
        }

        let gravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [sideMenuContainerView])
        gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(gravityDirectionX,  0)
        animator.addBehavior(gravityBehavior)

        let collisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [sideMenuContainerView])
        collisionBehavior.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("menuBoundary", fromPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryPointX, boundaryPointY),
            toPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryPointX, height))
        animator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)

        let pushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [sideMenuContainerView], mode: UIPushBehaviorMode.Instantaneous)
        pushBehavior.magnitude = pushMagnitude
        animator.addBehavior(pushBehavior)

        let menuViewBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [sideMenuContainerView])
        menuViewBehavior.elasticity = 0.25
        animator.addBehavior(menuViewBehavior)

    }
    else {
        var destFrame :CGRect
        if (menuPosition == .Left) {
            destFrame = CGRectMake((shouldOpen) ? -2.0 : -menuWidth, 0, menuWidth, height)
        }
        else {
            destFrame = CGRectMake((shouldOpen) ? width-menuWidth : width+2.0,
                0,
                menuWidth,
                height)
        }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            animationDuration,
            animations: { () -> Void in
                self.sideMenuContainerView.frame = destFrame
            },
            completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                if (self.isMenuOpen) {
                    self.delegate?.sideMenuDidOpen?()
                } else {
                    self.delegate?.sideMenuDidClose?()
                }
        })
    }

    if (shouldOpen) {
        delegate?.sideMenuWillOpen?()
    } else {
        delegate?.sideMenuWillClose?()
    }

    /*let outterView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(sideMenuContainerView.frame.width, 0,
        sourceView.frame.width - sideMenuContainerView.frame.width,
        sourceView.frame.height))
    outterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideSideMenu")
    outterView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    outterView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    sourceView.addSubview(outterView)
    sourceView.layer.zPosition = 0

    outterView.userInteractionEnabled = shouldOpen */


}

public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer is UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        let swipeGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as! UISwipeGestureRecognizer
        if !self.allowLeftSwipe {
            if swipeGestureRecognizer.direction == .Left {
                return false
            }
        }

        if !self.allowRightSwipe {
            if swipeGestureRecognizer.direction == .Right {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    else if gestureRecognizer.isEqual(panRecognizer) {
        if allowPanGesture == false {
            return false
        }
        animator.removeAllBehaviors()
        let touchPosition = gestureRecognizer.locationOfTouch(0, inView: sourceView)
        if menuPosition == .Left {
            if isMenuOpen {
                if touchPosition.x < menuWidth {
                    return true
                }
            }
            else {
                if touchPosition.x < 25 {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if isMenuOpen {
                if touchPosition.x > CGRectGetWidth(sourceView.frame) - menuWidth {
                    return true
                }
            }
            else {
                if touchPosition.x > CGRectGetWidth(sourceView.frame)-25 {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    }
    return true
}

internal func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    toggleMenu((self.menuPosition == .Right && gesture.direction == .Left)
        || (self.menuPosition == .Left && gesture.direction == .Right))
}

internal func handlePan(recognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    let leftToRight = recognizer.velocityInView(recognizer.view).x > 0

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .Began:

        break

    case .Changed:

        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(sourceView).x
        let xPoint : CGFloat = sideMenuContainerView.center.x + translation + (menuPosition == .Left ? 1 : -1) * menuWidth / 2

        if menuPosition == .Left {
            if xPoint <= 0 || xPoint > CGRectGetWidth(self.sideMenuContainerView.frame) {
                return
            }
        }else{
            if xPoint <= sourceView.frame.size.width - menuWidth || xPoint >= sourceView.frame.size.width
            {
                return
            }
        }

        sideMenuContainerView.center.x = sideMenuContainerView.center.x + translation
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: sourceView)

    default:

        let shouldClose = menuPosition == .Left ? !leftToRight && CGRectGetMaxX(sideMenuContainerView.frame) < menuWidth : leftToRight && CGRectGetMinX(sideMenuContainerView.frame) >  (sourceView.frame.size.width - menuWidth)

        toggleMenu(!shouldClose)

    }
}

private func updateSideMenuApperanceIfNeeded () {
    if (needUpdateApperance) {
        var frame = sideMenuContainerView.frame
        frame.size.width = menuWidth
        sideMenuContainerView.frame = frame
        sideMenuContainerView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: sideMenuContainerView.bounds).CGPath

        needUpdateApperance = false
    }
}

/**
 Toggles the state of the side menu.
 */
public func toggleMenu () {
    if (isMenuOpen) {
        toggleMenu(false)
    }
    else {
        updateSideMenuApperanceIfNeeded()
        toggleMenu(true)
    }
}
/**
 Shows the side menu if the menu is hidden.
 */
public func showSideMenu () {
    if (!isMenuOpen) {
        toggleMenu(true)
    }
}
/**
 Hides the side menu if the menu is showed.
 */
public func hideSideMenu () {
    if (isMenuOpen) {
        toggleMenu(false)
    }
}
}

extension ENSideMenu: UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate {
public func dynamicAnimatorDidPause(animator: UIDynamicAnimator) {
    if (self.isMenuOpen) {
        self.delegate?.sideMenuDidOpen?()
    } else {
        self.delegate?.sideMenuDidClose?()
    }
}

public func dynamicAnimatorWillResume(animator: UIDynamicAnimator) {
    print("resume")
}
}
```

This is my ENSideMenuNavigationController.swift

```
import UIKit

public class ENSideMenuNavigationController: UINavigationController, ENSideMenuProtocol {

public var sideMenu : ENSideMenu?
public var sideMenuAnimationType : ENSideMenuAnimation = .Default


// MARK: - Life cycle
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

public init( menuViewController: UIViewController, contentViewController: UIViewController?) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    if (contentViewController != nil) {
        self.viewControllers = [contentViewController!]
    }

    sideMenu = ENSideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuViewController: menuViewController, menuPosition:.Right)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(navigationBar)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

public override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Navigation
public func setContentViewController(contentViewController: UIViewController) {
    self.sideMenu?.toggleMenu()
    switch sideMenuAnimationType {
    case .None:
        self.viewControllers = [contentViewController]
        break
    default:
        contentViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        self.setViewControllers([contentViewController], animated: true)
        break
    }

}

}
```

This is my MyMenuTableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MyMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var selectedMenuItem : Int = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Customize apperance of table view
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(116.0, 0, 0, 0) //
    tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    tableView.scrollsToTop = false
    tableView.allowsSelection = false

    // Preserve selection between presentations
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedMenuItem, inSection: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .Middle)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL")

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        let selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell!.frame.size.width, cell!.frame.size.height))
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView
    }

    //cell!.textLabel?.text = "social Network #\(indexPath.row+1)"
    cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Facebook")


    return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 45.0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("did select row: \(indexPath.row)")

    if (indexPath.row == selectedMenuItem) {
        return
    }

    selectedMenuItem = indexPath.row

    //Present new view controller
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
    var destViewController : UIViewController
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1")
        break
    case 1:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2")
        break
    case 2:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3")
        break
    default:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController4")
        break
    }
    sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destViewController)
}
}
```

This is my MyNavigationController.swift

```
import UIKit

class MyNavigationController: ENSideMenuNavigationController, ENSideMenuDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sideMenu = ENSideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuViewController: MyMenuTableViewController(), menuPosition:.Right)
    //sideMenu?.delegate = self //optional
    sideMenu?.menuWidth = 90.0 // optional, default is 160
    // sideMenu?.bouncingEnabled = false
    //sideMenu?.allowPanGesture = false
    // make navigation bar showing over side menu
    view.bringSubviewToFront(navigationBar)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - ENSideMenu Delegate
func sideMenuWillOpen() {
    print("sideMenuWillOpen")
}

func sideMenuWillClose() {
    print("sideMenuWillClose")
}

func sideMenuDidClose() {
    print("sideMenuDidClose")
}

func sideMenuDidOpen() {
    print("sideMenuDidOpen")
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Comment: Downvote: please add code, framework you use for you side bar etc.

Comment: I've edited my post. Sorry

Comment: No problem, I removed my downvote ;)

Comment: Did you find the proper solution for that? I have also same issue @devtimg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your menu tableViewController you should implement

```
let MinHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let tHeight = tableView.bounds.height

    let temp = tHeight/CGFloat(items.count)  //Item size on your side menu

    return temp > MinHeight ? temp : MinHeight
}
```